# Android Studio: weird problems with imported library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to create an android app using Android Studio (gradle 8) and a public github library: [AndroidUSBCamera](https://github.com/jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera).

I don't think I'm facing library-related problems, but dependency / gradle / android studio problems instead.

I imported the library like this in **build.gradle**

`implementation 'com.github.jiangdongguo.AndroidUSBCamera:libausbc:3.3.3'`

## Problem 1: compile-time "fake" error

I can navigate kotlin source code of the imported library in Android Studio:

1. There is a "base" abstract class called ICamera

```
class MultiCameraClient(ctx: Context, callback: IDeviceConnectCallBack?) 
{
    //[...] skipping code

    /**
     * Camera strategy super class
     *
     * @property ctx context
     * @property device see [UsbDevice]
     * @constructor Create camera by inherit it
     */
    abstract class ICamera(val ctx: Context, val device: UsbDevice) : 
        Handler.Callback,
        H264EncodeProcessor.OnEncodeReadyListener 
    {
         //[...] skipping code
    }
}
```

2. There is a "derived" class CameraUVC that extends ICamera

```
class CameraUVC(ctx: Context, device: UsbDevice) : MultiCameraClient.ICamera(ctx, device) 
{
     //[...] skipping code
}
```

3. The derived class is implicitly a base class variable (sample library method)

```
    /**
     * Generate camera
     *
     * @param ctx context [Context]
     * @param device Usb device, see [UsbDevice]
     * @return Inheritor assignment camera api policy
     */
    protected open fun generateCamera(ctx: Context, device: UsbDevice) : MultiCameraClient.ICamera {
        return CameraUVC(ctx, device)
    }
```

I'm trying to replicate point 3 in my java code:

```
import com.jiangdg.ausbc.camera.CameraUVC;
import com.jiangdg.ausbc.MultiCameraClient;

    protected MultiCameraClient.ICamera generateCamera(Context ctx, UsbDevice device) {
        return new CameraUVC(ctx, device);
    }
```

I got this error

`Incompatible types. Found: 'com.jiangdg.ausbc.camera.CameraUVC', required: 'com.jiangdg.ausbc.MultiCameraClient.ICamera'`

Makes no sense (tried different ways - for example with explicit casting - same error). If I try to run the app, it works fine...

## Problem 2: cannot import specific package

I can import and use MultiCameraClient object and its constructor

```
import com.jiangdg.ausbc.MultiCameraClient;

MultiCameraClient manager = new MultiCameraClient(app, new IDeviceConnectCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onAttachDev(@Nullable UsbDevice usbDevice) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDetachDec(@Nullable UsbDevice usbDevice) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectDev(@Nullable UsbDevice usbDevice, @Nullable com.jiangdg.usb.USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock usbControlBlock) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDisConnectDec(@Nullable UsbDevice usbDevice, @Nullable com.jiangdg.usb.USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock usbControlBlock) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelDev(@Nullable UsbDevice usbDevice) {

            }
        });
```

I got this error

`error: package com.jiangdg.usb.USBMonitor does not exist`

infact I cannot import it BUT I can navigate the kotlin source code.

I found that the library I'm using has its own inner libraries (in the github source code)

```
    implementation project(path: ':libuvc')
    api project(path: ':libnative')
```

It seems that "api" expose the content of the package, but "implementation" not (I can import packages under libnative project; I cannot import packages under libuvc project, such as com.jiangdg.usb).

Is this a library configuration error?
Maybe the developer wants to keep some class hidden, but if I need to use it in a public constructor I'm blocked.

Can't Android Studio expose the inner package? I can see it in the dependency tree.

If not, is there any other way to explicitly import libuvc package?
I found libuvc.aar in the source code. Tried importing it like so

`implementation files('../libs/libuvc-3.2.9.aar')`

I got this error

`Duplicate class com.jiangdg.common.BaseActivity found in modules libuvc-3.2.9-runtime (libuvc-3.2.9.aar) and libuvc-3.3.3-runtime (com.github.jiangdongguo.AndroidUSBCamera:libuvc:3.3.3)`

Comment: "Is this a library configuration error?" -- you would have to ask the library author what their intentions were. "Maybe the developer wants to keep some class hidden, but if I need to use it in a public constructor I'm blocked" -- you would have to ask the library author what their intentions are. Perhaps you are not supposed to be creating your own `MultiCameraClient` implementation.

Comment: You're right.. but in general, is it correct to have a class "half exposed"? I thought it was not even possible. I don't get why I can see the source code in Android Studio, but can't import those packages

Comment: "is it correct to have a class "half exposed"?" -- it certainly seems like an oversight. I can see wanting to hide the implementation details, but then the API should have a richer set of interfaces, so your code only needs to reference the interfaces. "I don't get why I can see the source code in Android Studio, but can't import those packages" -- `implementation()` says "this dependency is not part of the public API of this library". It does not prevent a tool from downloading source code associated with that dependency. Those are completely independent concepts.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

1. The First error you are encountering seems to be related to the type you are returning [CameraUVC] is not recognised as a sub type of [MultiCameraClient.ICamera]
2. Ensure CameraUVC is correctly imported as an inner class of MultiCameraClient

**Problem 2**

The Package com.jiangdg.usb.USBMonitor is not being recognised this could be due to the library not properly exposing this Package
add this dependency to your build.gradle to include the 'libuvc' project

```
implementation project(':libuvc')
```

this may solve your issue and duplicate class error suggests that their might be a conflict between versions, you should remove direct AAR inclusion and should use library through dependency